# Content Processor Parameters in XNA 4 - what is missing?

Tags: xna, parameterized, xna-4.0

I have a content processor in my XNA project and I would like to add a couple of parameters so I can control its behaviour for certain files in Visual Studio.

I follow the second section of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975253.aspx, which is the same info as on many other sites, however when I try to specify a property as a parameter I get "type or namespace cannot be found" for the three attributes.

Its probably something like a missing 'using' statement but without a working example project I can't find out what/where the namespace is.

Comment: whats the new content you are adding? (Just curious)

Comment: @spooks, Hi, my new content consists essentially of a replacement Model class which I imaginatively call BasicModel, along with an equally creatively named StandardEffect. My BasicModel has a number of pet features such as CPU copies of geometry for collision detection, and the support for dual pass alpha 'sorting' built into the draw methods; most importantly I can subclass it, and hopefully with a couple of tweaks serialize at runtime without GS4 (for user generated content).
My content processor and associated Readers & Writers create the model and when appropriate apply the

Comment: Effect subclass, but I want to be able to control its behaviour - for example use BasicEffect for one file instead of replacing with StandardEffect, do or do not create copies of the geometry, save out animations, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find these classes in the System.ComponentModel assembly/namespace. For example, here's the [MSDN documentation for the DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! All this time I thought I was looking for an XNA specific property.